# Function to convert IP address in Integer using sql which will run on any database

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

I wrote function

```
CREATE FUNCTION ip2int(text) RETURNS bigint AS $$ 
SELECT split_part($1,'.',1)::bigint*16777216 + split_part($1,'.',2)::bigint*65536 +
 split_part($1,'.',3)::bigint*256 + split_part($1,'.',4)::bigint;
$$ LANGUAGE SQL  IMMUTABLE RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT;

SELECT ip2int('200.233.1.2');
```

which works on postgres database.
But when I run it on Oracle It gave me following error

> Error(1,21): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one
>   of the following: in out   long double ref char time timestamp interval
>   date binarynational character nchar

What is the solution for this?
Is there any way to make it database independent?

Comment: In general ANSI SQL is the most portable SQL, but when it comes to stored procedures only a very few dbms products follow the standard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realize that in PostgreSQL it's common to refer to one of the more commonly used programming languages as "plsql", but the language supported by PostgreSQL is properly known as "plpgsql", and PL/SQL and PL/pgSQL are two similar-but-different languages. The syntax of this function is not valid PL/SQL as defined by Oracle. PL/SQL does not use $$ to quote the text of the routine; the `text` parameter is untyped, which is not allowed in PL/SQL; PL/SQL does not support the $1, $2, etc parameter markers; `bigint` isn't supported in Oracle (although you could define a subtype of NUMBER to handle this); Oracle doesn't support the `::` cast operator; doesn't provide `split_part` (although I suppose you could write your own); and doesn't use the `LANGUAGE SQL IMMUTABLE`... stuff at the end. Oracle requires that a function consist of a statement block (`DECLARE...BEGIN...END`), while this function is purely a SELECT statement; and the SELECT statement in the function isn't valid for Oracle because Oracle requires a FROM clause. So, basically, this function is not valid PL/SQL. You could transform it into something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ip2int(text IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  nRetval  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '[0-9]', 1, 1)) * 16777216 +
           TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '[0-9]', 1, 2)) * 65536 +
           TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '[0-9]', 1, 3)) * 256 +
           TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(text, '[0-9]', 1, 4))
    INTO nRetval
    FROM DUAL;

  RETURN nRetval;
END IP2INT;
```

but making such radical alterations doesn't seem to be what you want to do.

[The PostgreSQL documentation on converting from PL/SQL to PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/plpgsql-porting.html) might give you some ideas of the challenges involved in this.

Best of luck.

Comment: To be precise: Postgres does not use $$ "*to mark the beginning and end of the routine*" - that is simply an alternative way of writing a string literal. It is not limited to the body of a function, e.g. `insert into foo (bar) values ($$some value$$);` is perfectly valid

Comment: Btw: you don't need the `select .. into`. You can use `return to_number()...` directly.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - you're right, but I was trying to mirror the OP's method as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_part(string VARCHAR2, delimiter VARCHAR2, n NUMBER)
    RETURN VARCHAR2
  IS
    v_start NUMBER(5) := 1;
    v_end NUMBER(5);
  BEGIN
    -- Find the position of n-th -1 delimiter
    IF n > 1 THEN
      v_start := INSTR(string, delimiter, 1, n - 1);

       -- Delimiter not found
       IF v_start = 0 THEN
          RETURN NULL;
       END IF;

       v_start := v_start + LENGTH(delimiter);

    END IF;

    -- Find the position of n-th delimiter
    v_end := INSTR(string, delimiter, v_start, 1);

    -- If not found return until the end of string
    IF v_end = 0 THEN
      RETURN SUBSTR(string, v_start);
    END IF;

    RETURN SUBSTR(string, v_start, v_end - v_start);
  END;


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ip2int(text IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
  nRetval  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT TO_NUMBER(split_part(text,'.',1)) * 16777216 +
           TO_NUMBER(split_part(text,'.',2)) * 65536 +
           TO_NUMBER(split_part(text,'.',3)) * 256 +
           TO_NUMBER(split_part(text,'.',4))
    INTO nRetval
    FROM DUAL;

  RETURN nRetval;
END IP2INT;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create or replace FUNCTION ip_to_number(ip IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN NUMBER
AS
    a varchar(20 char);
    b varchar(20 char);
    c varchar(20 char);
    d varchar(20 char);
    i integer;
    j integer;
    k integer;
    ip_value integer;
begin
    i := instr(ip, '.');
    j := instr(ip, '.', 1, 2);
    k := instr(ip, '.', 2, 3);
    if (k = 0) then
        raise_application_error(-20101, 'Incorrect IP format (missing at least one dot)');
    end if;
    a := substr(ip, 1, i - 1);
    b := substr(ip, i + 1, j - i - 1);
    c := substr(ip, j + 1, k - j - 1);
    d := substr(ip, k + 1);
    if (a not between 0 and 255) or (b not between 0 and 255) or (c not between 0 and 255) or (d not between 0 and 255) then
        raise_application_error(-20102, 'Incorrect IP format (octet out of bounds)');
    end if;
    ip_value := to_number(a) * 16777216 +  to_number(b) * 65536 +  to_number(c) * 256 + to_number(d);
    RETURN ip_value;
end;
```

Comment: Hi ! It would be better if you checkout [Answering Questions Format](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for future endeavor at Stack overflow. -Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it onflight:

```
select TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)) * power(2, 24) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)) * power(2, 16) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 3)) * power(2, 8) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 4))
from dual;
```

in this block you can easily check this translation

```
declare
    YourIpAddress varchar2(32) := '192.168.1.1';
    res number;
begin
select TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 1)) * power(2, 24) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 2)) * power(2, 16) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 3)) * power(2, 8) +
       TO_NUMBER(REGEXP_SUBSTR(YourIpAddress, '[0-9]+', 1, 4))
    into res
    from dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(res);
end;
```

on this [site](https://www.browserling.com/tools/dec-to-ip) you can check correctness.